# Error when handling touch on UIImageView in a cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I don't know why this is happening, but I get this error:

> -[__NSArrayM section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e53b70 2012-01-07 15:35:44.108 Timely1[51661:15203] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayM section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7e53b70'

when `handleTouch` is activated. Here is my code for adding the image and tap gesture.

```
[cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.PNG"]];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];   
[tapped release];
```

and then my code for handling the touch:

```
-(void)handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array count] inSection:1];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.PNG"]];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:array] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

**UPDATE:** How about if I wanted to uncheck it (like toggling it) does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: It seems to me that problem that you have faced earlier lies in line - NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array count] inSection:1]; Instead you need to use NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array count]-1 inSection:1];

Comment: yeah, but do you know how to fix `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:array] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` because I figured out that that was the problem but if I want to reload a cell again i can't use that line anymore.

Comment: Are you passing object of NSIndexPath in the array?

Comment: well here is how I declare my array: `array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:db.dbArray];` and dbArray is a array full of all my saved data.

Comment: and what is present in dbarray?have you printed that?are they kind of nsindexpath?

Comment: no there is no kind of indexpath and I havn't printed out anything. It just acts as a storage array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handleTouch method i think you could use:

```
UIImageView *cellImageView=(UIImageView *)gesture.view;
```

Comment: thanks that worked. The problem was `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:array] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`, thats what gave the error.

Comment: how about if I wanted to uncheck it (like toggling it) do u know how to do that?

Comment: this got me started but i needed even more data then just the state of my image so I decided to create a category extension `@interface UITapGestureRecognizer (Utility)` that adds an additional property `@property (nonatomic, strong) id userData;` called userData to place & later retrieve args I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with a `UIButton` as my checkbox and subclassing my `UITableViewCell`, it seems easier and more logical especially with the toggling bit.